NVIDIA Triton | llama2 | Python backend | Not getting request parameter and logs
I am using this code as a setting
name: "llama2"
backend: "python"
input [
  {
    name: "prompt"
    data_type: TYPE_STRING  
    dims: [1]
  }
]
output [
  {
    name: "generated_text"
    data_type: TYPE_STRING  
    dims: [1]
  }
]

parameters: {
  key: "EXECUTION_ENV_PATH",
  value: {string_value: "/mnt/data/model_repository/llama2/pbtxt_name.tar.gz"}
}

instance_group [
  {
    count: 1
    kind: KIND_GPU
  }
]

and this code in the execute method inside "model.py"
def execute(self, requests):
        logger = pb_utils.Logger
        logger.log("execute-Specific Msg!", logger.INFO)
        responses = []
        for request in requests:
            logger.log_info("request specific ")
            print(request)
            # Decode the Byte Tensor into Text
            inputs = pb_utils.get_input_tensor_by_name(request, "prompt")
            logger.log_info("inputs before numpy ")

            inputs = inputs.as_numpy()
            logger.log_info("inputs after numpy ")
            logger.log_info(inputs)
            DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT = """You are a helpful AI assistant. Keep short answers of no more than 2 sentences."""

            prompts = [self.get_prompt(i[0].decode(), [], DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT) for i in inputs]
           ...........

the triton model is also loading fine
I0624 ************ 1 model_lifecycle.cc:264] ModelStates()
I0624 ************ 1 server.cc:633] 
+--------+---------+--------+
| Model  | Version | Status |
+--------+---------+--------+
| llama2 | 1       | READY  |
+--------+---------+--------+

I0624 ************ 1 metrics.cc:864] Collecting metrics for GPU 0: NVIDIA A10G
I0624 ************ 1 metrics.cc:757] Collecting CPU metrics

but when I am doing simple inference via curl command like this
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000/v2/models/llama2/infer' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
  "inputs":[
    {
      "name": "prompt", 
      "shape": [1],
      "datatype": "BYTES",
      "data":  ["capital of India"]
    }
    ]
  }'

I am not getting any results, here is the summary

No log printed with dynamic value like actual value of 'input','request'

Getting error on this line "prompts = [self.get_prompt(i[0].decode(), [], DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT) for i in inputs]", the error is
tritonclient.utils.InferenceServerException: [400] Failed to process the request(s) for model instance 'llama2_0', message: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'


it seems to be some basic issue but I am not able to find it, it took a lot of time and money on the GPU, can someone please help me
I am following this path : https://blog.marvik.ai/2023/10/16/deploying-llama2-with-nvidia-triton-inference-server/
